# Portainer rootless mode not show docker stats

Tags: docker, portainer

I followed the next guide to create rootless mode
https://www.portainer.io/blog/portainer-and-rootless-docker

The containers work correctly but i can't see their statistics with the next error

"runc did not terminate successfully: exit status 1: unable to get all container pids: lstat : no such file or directory : unknown"

My command for create portainer was

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9443:9443 --name=portainer -v    /run/user/1000/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data  portainer/portainer- ce:2.19.1-alpine
```

another data:

export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/app/project/docker
```

anyone know the problem? Thx